# How to Read xml value from system folder(Rooted)?

Tags: android, xml

I am new to android programming. I am trying to read xml value from system folder. Below .

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes("mount -o remount rw /data");
os.writeBytes("chmod 777 data/data/com.aas.a/pref.xml");
```

at pref.xml. Here are the values !

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<a>
<string name="aas"/>
<string pass="123"/>
</a>
```

I want to retreive 123 from this xml. But I don't know how to .Please help me ! Thank you so much !